# If the prequels aren't canon, why is Kylo Ren so similar to Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

[Hayden Christensen's performance](http://www.melty.com/star-wars-episode-vii-the-force-awakens-hayden-christensen-to-play-darth-vader-in-episode-viii-a1919.html) as Anakin was apparently not well-received. However, the actor depicted to chose Kylo Ren looks pretty similar to the prequel's Anakin:

[image]

Ignoring the fact that he looks nothing like Han or Leia, the resemblance seems to draw upon the fact that he is the grandson of Anakin. Furthermore, Kylo Ren has explosive bouts of rage and is quite angsty. However, if they decided to disregard the prequels as canon, they could've made him look or act completely different from Anakin (sans the similarity to Vader). Why did they choose to emulate Christensen's Prequel Anakin?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking. First, the prequels *are* canon (who told you otherwise?). Second, Adam Driver (the actor who plays Kylo Ren) looks nothing like Hayden Christensen. Whether he acts similarly or not is very subjective. It doesn't look like Kylo is emulating pre-Vader Anakin at all. So what *is* your question?

Comment: IMHO he kinda does resemble Hayden in some regards. It was one of the first things I noticed when he removes his helmet the first time. That said, there's nothing to indicate that the prequels are non-canon...

Comment: Adam Driver looks a hell of a lot more like Harrison Ford than like Hayden Christensen. But even if he didn't and the prequels were not canon, these things happen. I don't look much like either of my birth parents, but I'm the spitting image of my (completely unrelated) stepmother. Go figure.

Comment: Dear lord, what wouldn't I give to make the prequels noncanonical!?!?  Sadly, though, they are every bit as canonical as the original trilogy...

Answer (score 6):

- The prequels are [fully Disney canon](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/)
- Many people agree that the problem with H.C's performance wasn't his lack of acting ability (apparently he acted well in other films), but poor script (Hi George!), poor directing (Hi George!) and poor chemistry with Natalie Portman (likely caused by the dialog too - Hi George!)
- The reason he's similar to Anakin is because he basically repeats Anakin's arc - both storytelling wise (young Jedi hopeful turned bad and killed all his fellow Jedi he could, destroying Jedi order), and in-universe (he adores Darth Vader, and tries to emulate him). Oh, and he's Vader's grandson. So resemblance is not unexpected, even if personally I really don't see where "similar looks" statement comes from.

Comment: The only visual similarity I can see is the unruly hairdo which is kinda similar to the one Anakin had during Ep. III.

Comment: @BMWurm - well, they are both humanoid males. Since when is anything more than that was needed to kick off a fan theory? :)

Comment: Well, at least it means Kylo isn't JarJar...., it does, right? **Please** tell me it does!!